# how do i write an extension method on ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, extension-methods

I have a ConcurrentDictionary object defined as `ConcurrentDictionary<int, DirtyFlag><int, DirtyFlag>` where dirty flag is an Enum which has Dirty/Clean values.

I am trying to write an extension method to get only Dirty objects. Those objects that has DirtyFlag set to Dirty.

I tried using this but it gives me an error:

```
public static ConcurrentDictionary<int, DirtyFlag> GetDirtyRoutes(this ConcurrentDictionary<int, DirtyFlag> wholeDictionary)
{

    return wholeDictionary.SelectMany(a => a.Value == DirtyFlag.Dirty);

}
```

This is the error message that i am getting:

```
The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>
(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, 
System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot 
be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Any help?

Comment: You can get answer to your question at this link

http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2025/extension-methods-to-make-concurrentdictionary-getoradd-and-addorupdate-thread-sa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static ConcurrentDictionary<int, DirtyFlag> GetDirtyRoutes(this ConcurrentDictionary<int, DirtyFlag> wholeDictionary)
{
    return new ConcurrentDictionary<int, DirtyFlag>(
        wholeDictionary.Where(a => a.Value == DirtyFlag.Dirty)
    );
}
```